# cells updating according to each other values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So the idea is to have a set sum value for 2 or more cells and if we change one of the cells value, it distripute the changed value on the other connected cells.

⠀

Let's say we have 2 Clients paying for the same Item:

**Client 1 payed the full $100**
[image]

⠀

⠀

**Then Client 2 payed $30 to us, which then we pay client 1 back**
[image]

⠀

⠀

**Then Client 2 Personally payed Client 1 $20**
[image]

so the question is:
Can I have 2 or more cells updating their values according to each other.

⠀

Edit1:
I didn't say what are the changing variables are.
`Clients`: there can be more than 2
`Item`: unchanging
`Price`: chainging

Comment: Is there always just one item and two clients? If the `price` gets updated, should the client cells be updated too? Consider explaining in more detail all the possible updates that can happen here. Also, are you open to using [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview)?

Comment: Yes, I am willing to use the Scripts. as for the `price` getting updated, the idea is for the `Clients` values to not update till one of them gets updated manually, then for the script to check the `Price` and do the calculations(if there is more money than it's being paid, distribute the rest of the price to the other `Clients`). I don't want to ask for too much, so if you can just point me in the right direction⠀⠀ Edit: fixed my wording

Comment: Isn't the sum of the columns always the price?  Whether Client 2 pays you or Client 1, the sum is still the same, the price?

Comment: And if I'm not mistaken Payed Amount is (client payed)-(price/client)?

Comment: this is a rough example so take it with a pinch of salt. i just wanted to highlight the fact that i need 2 cells or more to have the sum of a set value, But the cells values could be changed.

Comment: I believe you have to do it via app script.  If Client 1 pays $0 and Client 2 pays $100 then there has to be a formula for Client 2 if Client 1 pays something.  But you have to have a formula for Client 1 if Client 2 pays something.  So you can't have both a formula and the ability to input a value.

Comment: yeah, I didn't find a formula that I can use without it breaking up duo to "Circular dependency". I don't have any experience using scripts so I don't know where to start

Comment: When there are more than 2 clients, I think this becomes undetermined. In this case, when modifying one of the client values, how do we know which client/s is getting/sending that money?